When building from source, where does the polars wheel install to?
I can't find any mention of this and looked at the source code. I can build the wheel without any problem and the process says it gets installed. But to where?


Typically packages are installed in a path such as /usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages

Right. But it's not there via pip list.

It seems to create a polars.pth file in py-polars/../polars/.venv/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages which points at py-polars/polars - so you'd need to activate the venv?

It sure did. Right at the base of the polars path, there a .venv folder. Man... Now to figure out how to get it to install that super optimized binary in the Python of my choosing. Good eye @jqurious
